# How to select text option from select menu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am attempting to select the text that is shown in my select menu. On change I would like to know what text was select and not the value.

I am able to do this for the value with `this.value` but when attempting to do `this.label` or `this.text` I am getting an undefined return.

How can I get the text shown in the drop down menu and not the value?

If I do `this.title`then its showing the title of my select menu not the actual the title of the option

Here is an example of my code:

```js
$("#test").change(function() {
  let selectValue = this.value
  console.log(selectValue)

  let title = this.title
  console.log((this.options[this.selectedIndex]))

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test" title="test">
  <option value="high school">Academic</option>
  <option value="online">Retail</option>
</select>
```

I am expecting to see a return value "Academic" and not "high school" or "Retail" and not "online"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the selected option by `this.options` and `this.selectedIndex`

```
console.log(this.options[this.selectedIndex])
```

```js
$("#test").change(function() {
  let selectedOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex];

  console.log(selectedOption.innerHTML);
  console.log($(selectedOption).text());
  console.log($(selectedOption).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test" title="test">
  <option value="high school">Academic</option>
  <option value="online">Retail</option>
</select>
```

Comment: could you provide a code example? this returns the full <option value="high school">Academic</option> for me and not the actual text. Run code snippet above for an example

Comment: You can then get the option by `.innerHTML`